# How do you get rid of the quote of the day / fortune messeges each time you open a new console?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, apt

I have an ubuntu computer.

Each time I open the console there is some animal in ascii art and a quote.

How can I uninstall this and get a normal command line?

All accounts have this, so it is global on this machine.

Example:

```
 ________________________________________
( Celebrate Hannibal Day this year. Take )
( an elephant to lunch.                  )
 ----------------------------------------
       o   ,__,
        o  (oo)____
           (__)    )\
              ||--|| *
```

Comment: I'm *pretty* sure this does not ship with Ubuntu by default ;) So what did you do to that poor computer? Installed any custom MOTD? What's the content of `/etc/update-motd.d/`? Edited your shell's profile or configuration files?

Comment: I did not say it shipped. Maybe someone installed it. I hope I can get an answer. sudo ls /etc/update-motd.d/
00-header     20-cpu-checker     91-release-upgrade 99-footer
10-help-text  90-updates-available  98-reboot-required

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the contents of Bash's system-wide configuration file:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/bash.bashrc &
```

See if there's a line with:

```
/usr/games/fortune
```

Comment it out and save:

```
#/usr/games/fortune
```

Then try to see if the message has gone away by restarting terminal.

---

The package responsible should be called `fortune`, so you can generally remove it by typing:

```
sudo apt-get remove fortune
```

On Linux Mint, the offending packages are removed like this:

```
sudo apt-get remove fortune-mod fortunes-husse fortunes-min
```

Of course, delete the line in `bash.bashrc` referring to those packages.

Comment: I appended your answer to mine, so the solution is in the right place :) Mind the difference between Linux Mint and Ubuntu though, that explains the difference in packages.

Comment: s/Uncomment/Comment/

Answer (score 1):

Also on Mint, Got to Menu > Preferences > Desktop Settings > Terminal : Uncheck 'Show fortune cookies'.

Im using Mint 13 (Maya) mate edition.